# Doctrine setparamers in wrong order

Tags: doctrine-orm

It seems that doctrine sets parameters in a wrong order. I have the following parameter array:

```
$params = array(
        1 => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
        2 => array(150, 12, 130),
        3 => 'CALLED',
        4 => array('ND', 'PF', 'OS'),
        5 => '2015-07-02 00:00:00',
        6 => '2015-07-05 00:00:00'
    );
```

And i have the following query

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
        SELECT c FROM Customers\Entity\Customer c
        WHERE c.customer_categories_id IN(?1)
        AND c.countries_id IN(?2)
        AND c.state = ?3
        AND c.potential_diamonds IN(?4)
        AND c.last_call NOT BETWEEN ?5 AND ?6
        ');

$query->setParameters($params);
$result = $query->getResult();
```

And this is the final query:

```
SELECT c0_.id AS id_0, c0_.company AS company_1, c0_.vat_number AS vat_number_2, c0_.first_name AS first_name_3, c0_.last_name AS last_name_4, c0_.phone AS phone_5, c0_.phone2 AS phone2_6, c0_.mobile AS mobile_7, c0_.email AS email_8, c0_.email2 AS email2_9, c0_.fax AS fax_10, c0_.address AS address_11, c0_.address2 AS address2_12, c0_.postal_code AS postal_code_13, c0_.town AS town_14, c0_.province AS province_15, c0_.countries_id AS countries_id_16, c0_.customer_titles_id AS customer_titles_id_17, c0_.customer_categories_id AS customer_categories_id_18, c0_.present_list AS present_list_19, c0_.vip_list AS vip_list_20, c0_.previous_sold AS previous_sold_21, c0_.previous_bought AS previous_bought_22, c0_.opening_hours AS opening_hours_23, c0_.main_office AS main_office_24, c0_.newsletter AS newsletter_25, c0_.website AS website_26, c0_.`state` AS state_27, c0_.potential_diamonds AS potential_diamonds_28, c0_.remarks AS remarks_29, c0_.date_created AS date_created_30, c0_.date_changed AS date_changed_31, c0_.last_call AS last_call_32, c0_.customer_languages_id AS customer_languages_id_33, c0_.display_state AS display_state_34, c0_.longitude AS longitude_35, c0_.latitude AS latitude_36 FROM customers c0_ WHERE c0_.customer_categories_id IN ('ND', '2015-07-05 00:00:00', 'CALLED', 130, 130, 'CALLED') AND c0_.countries_id IN ('ND', '2015-07-05 00:00:00', '2015-07-02 00:00:00') AND c0_.`state` = 'PF' AND c0_.potential_diamonds IN ('2015-07-02 00:00:00', 'OS', 'PF') AND c0_.last_call NOT BETWEEN 'OS' AND 12
```

if we look in the WHERE part of the query than we see that the parameters are completely flipped. This is very strange. does anyone have an explanation for this or have the same problem? There is not much to find on google.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When and where are you adding `$params` to your query? I would also use  `createQueryBuilder` (and submethods) instead of writing the whole sql query

Comment: i'm doing the setParameters right after the createQuery. I also tried with createQueryBuilder but it gives the same flipped parameters.

Comment: I guess you are doing `$query->setParameters($params);`, right? Can you paste the whole code? From the `$query` builder to the echo part.

Comment: hi, i just updated my question. so right under the createQuery action i do a setParameters and than fetch the result. but the results are off course incorrect.